# MVC3 The model item passed into the dictionary is of type '_320.Models.MyViewModel', but

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, list, foreach, viewmodel

I am passing a viewmodel into a view containing a foreach loop.  This viewmodel contains two lists.  These lists are filled using Linq.

With the following code, I get the following error:  The model item passed into the dictionary is of type '_320.Models.MyViewModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[_320.Models.MyViewModel]'.

I want to reach properties contained in the two lists in the ViewModel in my view's foreach loop.

***UPDATE***
I have been able to display the view by modifying the end of my controller code to:

```
List<MyViewModel> MyList = new List<MyViewModel>();
           MyList.Add(_myViewModel);
                return View(MyList);
```

However, it is an empty view with nothing but headers.  When I attempt to change my fields in my view from something like `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.rx.Rx_ID)` to `@Html.DisplayFor (modelItem => item.Rxes.rx.Rx_ID)` it is labeled red.  Is it impossible to access a property located that far down in a list?

***END OF UPDATE***

Model

```
public class MyViewModel
    {

        public Patient patient { get; set; }
        public Rx rx { get; set; }
        public Fill fill { get; set; }
        public List<Rx> Rxes { get; set; }
        public List<Fill> Fills { get; set; }
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult AllFilled()
        {
            MyViewModel _myViewModel = new MyViewModel();
            List<Fill> FillList = db.Fills.Where(p => p.Status == "Filled").ToList();
            List<Rx> RxList = new List<Rx>();
            Rx myRx = new Rx();
            foreach (var item in FillList)
            {
                myRx = db.Rxes.Single(p => p.Rx_ID == item.Rx_ID);
                RxList.Add(myRx);
            }
            _myViewModel.Fills = FillList;
            _myViewModel.Rxes = RxList;

                return View(_myViewModel);
            }
        }
```

View

```
@model IEnumerable<_320.Models.MyViewModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "AllFilled";
}

<h2>AllFilled</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            NDC
        </th>
        <th>
            Rx_ID
        </th>
        <th>
            Fill_ID
        </th>
        <th>
            Status
        </th>
        <th>
            Filled Date
        </th>
        <th>
            Filled By
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    {
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.rx.NDC)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.rx.Rx_ID)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem =>item.fill.Fill_ID)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.fill.Status)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.fill.Filled_Date)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.fill.Filled_By)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.rx.Rx_ID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your view is expecting a model of type IEnumerable<_320.Models.MyViewModel> due to the first line in the view.

```
@model IEnumerable<_320.Models.MyViewModel>
```

If you want to use a model object of type MyViewModel (as coded in your controller), change this line to

```
@model _320.Models.MyViewModel
```

Comment: when I do this I get an error about my model not containing a type of GetEnumerator

Comment: @foreach (var item in Model) line says, your Model is nothing but a list of MyViewModel objects each containing a fill and rx object as you are using them in your loop.

But you are filling up two separate lists of fill and rx objects in your controller in one MyViewModel object. Instead you need to create a List of MyViewModel and each one of them should have a fill and rx object.